# Php foreach echo (if/else)

Tags: php, json, api, if-statement, foreach

It prints on the screen when it is correctly entered, but I do not want to do anything when it is entered incorrectly

How can I do that?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');

$api_key = 'local';
$keyword = 'test';

$url = 'test.json' . $api_key . '&' .'keyword' .'=' . $GLOBALS['q'] ;

$open = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($open, true);

$istatistikler = $data['data'];
if ($data) {
foreach ( $istatistikler as $istatistik ){

    echo '<div class="right">';
    echo 'Oyun modu: ' . $istatistik['title'] . '<br />' .
    'Kazanma: ' . $istatistik['content'] . '<br />' .
    'Kazanma: ' . $istatistik['image'] . '<br />' .
    'Kazanma: ' . $istatistik['category'] . '<br />' .
    '<br />' .
    '<hr/>';
 $karakter_simge = 'http://google.com' . $istatistik['image'] . '';
 echo "<img src=".$karakter_simge." >" ;
 echo '</div>';
 }
  }
?>
```

[Successful output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQfa7.png)

Failed output

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://localhost/api/detail?X-Api-Key=local&keyword=a):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not
>   Acceptable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/weather-master/php/php-api.php on line
>   10

"I do not want to print unsuccessfully"

thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, I do not want to see

Comment: You should do that at your PHP configuration level. Disable the error displaying, that is best practice. You should check your logs for errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$open = file_get_contents($url);
```

into

```
$open = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($open === false)
    die("wrong");
```

The `@` suppresses the error message. Using `die()` will abort the script completely with the given message.

Alternatively, change the condition to `!== false` and wrap the rest of your "successful" code in its body:

```
$open = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($open !== false)
{
    $data = json_decode...
    ...
    ...
}
```

---

I guess I overshot the goal here a little, but not even running into code that won't work properly without its data isn't a bad idea at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:

```
$open = @file_get_contents($url);
```

`@` sign before a function name (in a call) prevents from showing any warnings (It's a bad practice though).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!